# Reverse map for $n \mapsto n^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

(sorry if I use wrong words, I study math in a different language).

I have $f: \mathbb N \mapsto \mathbb N $ with the rule $n \mapsto n^2$.
I want to find such $g$ that $gf = e$ (order matters: you apply $f$ first and $g$ after that to get identity map).

So I thought that $g$ might be $n \mapsto \sqrt n$ (since we know $n$ is a square, so we get $n \to n^2 \to n$). But my textbook asks me to give two examples of $g$. What is the second? Is the first one even correct?

Comment: I think it should me $\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$ not just $\sqrt{n}$

Comment: $n \mapsto \sqrt{n}$ is not well defined: indeed $\sqrt{2}$ is notoriously a natural number.

Comment: @Spinach But it's guaranteed that $\sqrt n$ is natural since $f$ produces squares. This shouldn't change much.

Comment: It does because the domain of $n \mapsto \sqrt n$ is supposed to be $\mathbb{N}$, not just the set of squared numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set $g(n)=\sqrt{n}$: you need a function $g$ with domain $\Bbb N$ such that $g(n)\in\Bbb N$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Thus, you can set $g(n)=\sqrt{n}$ only when $n$ is a perfect square. However, when $n$ is *not* a perfect square, you can let $g(n)$ be any natural number, so there are many different ways to choose $g$.